# How to install npm in a vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm-install

I tried to run npm run server command for my vue project but it keeps not working.

[image]

Comment: Just do no use directory name with the space...

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json

> The name is what your thing is called. Some rules:

- The name must be less than or equal to 214 characters. This includes the scope for scoped packages.
- The names of scoped packages can begin with a dot or an underscore. This is not permitted without a scope.
- New packages must not have uppercase letters in the name.
- The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command line, and a folder name. Therefore, the name can't contain any non-URL-safe characters.

Space is not url-safe.

Comment: Oh ok then you mean i should rename my project file without space and uppercase letters ? Or maybe i am wrong

Comment: In directory name delete space

Answer (score 0):

I think, maybe you just don't use directory name with the space.